# How to update bulk in SQLalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have an array of dictionaries as:

```
dict = [{"1": "name"}, {"2": "name1"}]
```

How to use bulk update rows by keys: `1 and 2`

So, I need perform this query: `UPDATE images set name = "name1" WHERE id = 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
session.bulk_update_mappings(
         images,
         dict
        )
```

**Explanation** (Straight from sqlalchemy documentation)

Perform a bulk update of the given list of mapping dictionaries.

The bulk update feature allows plain Python dictionaries to be used as the source of simple UPDATE operations which can be more easily grouped together into higher performing “executemany” operations.

Happy Coding!

Comment: It will do a lot of queries, if use loop. I know primary key and field that I need to update

Comment: Can you explain, commit will do only one query like? UPDATE SET...;UPDATE SET...;UPDATE SET;?

Comment: You can use the [bulk_update_mappings()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_update_mappings) function I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Can you share example please

Comment: I have updated my answer. Basically, the bulk_update_mappings() function takes in a mapper and mappings. So a mapper basically refers to the database column and mappings refer to your list of dictionaries and the function uses the list of dictionaries to update the database. The code in my answer should do the trick. Only modification you might have to make is to change the session variable to your database session object.